# flexbox conditional justify/align

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to have conditional css based on another property?

I want to write some helpers for flexbox alignment:

```
.center {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.center-x {
    ...
}
```

the content of center-x depends on wether the element has `flex-direction: column` or not

Can I somehow have center-x to behave differently depending on the elements flex direction?

Comment: If you're willing to use JavaScript, then certainly.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution? I can think of a solution, however as spacer mentions you are better off using javascript for this task.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer pure css/sass

Comment: How are you planning to add the style `flex-direction: column` to the css? Is it in run-time?

Comment: @GibinEalias no, it is added to the markup (.flex-column)

Comment: I believe you are planning to add the class name `flex-column` to the element in the HTML. In that case, why don't you write your generic styles in `.center-x{ }` and override it using `.center-x.flex-column{ }`, which contains the specific styles?

Comment: @GibinEalias Wouldn't then flex column need to be aware of .center-x? Because it should not override anything if center-x is not present as well, right?

Comment: Please see my answer below. Kindly let me know whether my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by OP, `flex-direction: column` property will be added to the HTML element using `flex-column` class.

In that case, I hope the below example would help.

```
.center-x {
  color: red;  //Color red
}

.center-x.flex-column{
  color: blue;  //Color red will be overridden with blue if the class 'flex-comunn' is present
}
```

### Possible Outputs

`<span class="center-x">Test</span>`  Color = red

`<span class="center-x flex-column">Test</span>`  Color = blue

`<span class="flex-column">Test</span>`  Color = default/parent color

`<span class="">Test</span>`  Color = default/parent color

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/VxpKMW)

Hope this helps.